# WSO2 Message Store parameter from registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

do you know if there is a way to inject a registry entry as a message store parameter value (like for instance a rabbitMQ user or password) in wso2 ei? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it looks like it is not possible out of the box.
What I've done to achieve this is to create my own custom message store (extending the existing RabbitMQStore) in order to allow to get some parameters from the registry.

I get the Message Context with the following call

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2Mc = this.newAxis2Mc();
context = this.newSynapseMc(axis2Mc);
```

The if the parameter value contains the patter "$registry:" I retrieve the actual value from the registry

```
Registry regInstance = context.getConfiguration().getRegistry();       
String val = ((OMTextImpl)regInstance.getResource(new Entry(key),null)).getText();
```